# net.ipv4.ip_forward=0 not persistent across reboots

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi with Debian Bookworm. I'm trying to prevent packet forwarding. I know that I can set like this `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0` but this is not persistent across reboots.

I've also tried add `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0` to the bottom of the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, and after a reboot the packet forward was active. I've also added a file (99-forward.conf) with that line in the `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory, the after a reboot the packet forward was still active.

More info:

- I'm checking if the ip forwarding is with `sysctl -n net.ipv4.ip_forward` and connecting with another cellphone to that interface (is an access point that I know that does not have internet access if the ip forward is inactive)
- If i run `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0` it works in the current boot
- Linux kernel: Linux 6.1.0-rpi7-rpi-v8 aarch64
- I have NetworkManager installed (is this helpful?)
- `ls -al /etc/sysctl.d` output

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 29 17:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 91 root root 4096 Feb 29 17:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   92 May 10  2023 98-rpi.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   55 Feb 29 17:01 99-forward.conf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   14 Nov 10 00:25 99-sysctl.conf -> ../sysctl.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  798 Dec 19  2022 README.sysctl
```

Comment: What do you get when you enter the following command: `systemctl status sysctl`?

Comment: @GAD3R
the systemd-sysctl.service is active and I've added the `ls -al /etc/sysctl.d` output to the question.

I know that I can just run `sudo sysctl -p` but I want my system to be resilient reboots. This is a company product that maybe rebooted and I want to keep packet forwarding always disabled.

@Seamus
"Unit sysctl.service could not be found". Interesting...

Comment: *"I have NetworkManager installed (is this helpful?)"*, yes, as that sysctl could be done by anything that needs IP forward support. Firewall management software could do that as well. Or things like docker or other forms of container management infrastructure.

Comment: `grep -r net.ipv4.ip_forward /etc /lib/systemd` might turn up something.

Comment: Does your system have more than one interface (other than `lo`)? What's the output of `ip a` or `ip r`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas
Yes, I have multiple interfaces (2 ethernet and 2 wifi). `grep -r net.ipv4.ip_forward /etc /lib/systemd` did not turn up anything valuable, sorry. Do you have any suggestion regarding the NetworkManager? I do not have any dockers or firewalls, I'm testing in a stock bookworm image with some minimal configurations.

Comment: Running tools like Docker (or other container handlers: LXC ...) or a VM hypervisor will activate (back) forwarding. Are you running these kind of tools?

Comment: NetworkManager will turn it on if you enable "sharing".

Comment: Does `grep -rw shared /etc/NetworkManager` return anything?

Comment: Output of `iptables-save` may report more clue as to what needs and has enabled the forwarding.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas
I think you found the problem! I had that connection with ipv4.method as shared.

Comment: This would seem to be an issue with `NetworkManager`...   Why else would a manually-set option in `/etc/sysctl.conf` be over-ridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discovered with the help of Stéphane Chazelas. Thank you for the help.

The problem is related to NetworkManager. I have an access point where its ipv4 method is set as shared. This caused the net.ipv4.ip_forward to be set to 1.

I still want my access point to be set as shared, so I found a workaround. I've added the following to the file `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-disable-ip-forward` and made it executable (`sudo chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-disable-ip-forward`).

```
#!/bin/sh

INTERFACE=$1
ACTION=$2

if [ "$INTERFACE" = "ap0" ] && [ "$ACTION" = "up" ]; then
    sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
    sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0
fi
```

When a network event occurs, NetworkManager runs scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` so it automatically sets the net.ipv4.ip_forward to 0.